# Update exception using JDBC on DB2

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

The code that causes the exception is the following:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < updateParams.size(); i++) {
        s = con.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        params = (String[][]) updateParams.get(i);
        setParamsPreparedStatement(s, params);
        log.debug("executeUpdates: " + sSQL + "[params:" + Arrays.deepToString(params) + "]");
        Date d = new Date();
        s.execute();
        log.info("STATEMENT EXECUTE TIME IN SECOND=" + (new Double(new Date().getTime() - d.getTime()) / 1000));
        rowcount += s.getUpdateCount();
        s.close();
    }
```

The exact row of the exception is s.execute.

The stracktrace is:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.fg.d(fg.java:1340)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gb.k(gb.java:351)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gb.a(gb.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.w.a(w.java:52)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.wb.c(wb.java:213)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.ab(gg.java:1779)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.d(gg.java:2324)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.d(gg.java:2420)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.X(gg.java:1332)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.execute(gg.java:1316)
```

The insert query is:

```
insert into CMP_RULES_ACTIONS (RULE_ID, ACTION_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID, creation_date, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, expiry_date, activation_date, enabled, priority, GROUP_ID, owner) values (?, ?, ?, sysdate, sysdate, to_date(?,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI'), to_date(?,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI'), 1, ?, ?, ?)
```

Params are:

```
[params:[[freebuy_wv_scomm_bonus_perc_863, 12], [sendgenericbonuslist, 12], [863, 4], [2101/01/31 00:00, 12], [2013/03/21 16:14, 12], [0, 4], [null, 12], [null, 12]]]
```

Googling the exception message gives nothing. I'm a newbie in DB2. Can anybody help me?

**UPDATE**

An example of how I set parameters in the preparedstatement:

```
public void setParamsPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement s, String[][] params) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Params are: " + Arrays.deepToString(params));
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        if (params[i][1].equals(ParamTypes.ORA_TYPE_INTEGER)) {
            if (params[i][0] != null && !params[i][0].trim().equals("")) {
                s.setInt(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(params[i][0]));
            } else {
                s.setNull(i + 1, Types.INTEGER);
            }
        }

 ...
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I was trying to put a long string into a field that was too short. Now the field is longer and my code succeeds.

Comment: When setting the parameters on the `PreparedStatement`, are you using 1-based indices?

Comment: Also, are those date columns `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`: a `DATE` column does not have a time portion, while a `TIMESTAMP` does (and therefor my require the use of `TO_TIMESTAMP` instead

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it was a problem of a field that was too short fo the value I was trying to insert.

Comment: Good to know. You could post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: You're using string concatenation in your logging, which kind-of defeats the purpose when different log-levels are disabled (ie the concatenation is still performed, which could be quite a bit of work).  Most logging utilities I'm aware of use a set of varags replacement variables, you should look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that a field, namely RULE_ID, was too short (VARCHAR(30) ) for the value that I was trying to insert ("freebuy_wv_scomm_bonus_perc_863").